# Reading In Adding Up Integers VB

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have created a text file with gaps in between. So I don't know how to read into the file and add the numbers up. It should basically add the numbers up and give a total. I am really stuck. I think you need to create a loop and another variable but I don't know where to add this.
 Thanks in advance:
Imports System.IO
Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim filename As String
    Console.WriteLine("This program will add up all the numbers in this program.")
    Console.WriteLine("Please type in the name of the file to view.")
    filename = Console.ReadLine()
    'Pass the file path and the file name to the StreamReader constructor.
    objStreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\Oliver\Documents\Computing\" + filename + ".txt")
    'Read the first line of text.
    strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine
    'Continue to read until you reach the end of the file.
    Do While Not strLine Is Nothing
        'Write the line to the Console window.
        Console.WriteLine(strLine)
        'Read the next line.
        strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine
    Loop
    objStreamReader.Close()
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of numbers you have in your file but you can try this. Also, instead of reading in a line first then looping, just loop and read lines and keep a running total as you go:

```
Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
Dim strLine As String
Dim filename As String
Dim total as Integer

Console.WriteLine("This program will add up all the numbers in this program.")
Console.WriteLine("Please type in the name of the file to view.")
filename = Console.ReadLine()

'Pass the file path and the file name to the StreamReader constructor.
objStreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\Oliver\Documents\Computing\" + filename + ".txt")

Do While Not objStreamReader.EndOfStream
    'Read line.
    strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine

    'Write the line to the Console window.
    Console.WriteLine(strLine)

    'If the line has data, add its value to total
    if strLine.Trim.length > 0 then
       total += CInt(strLine.Trim)
    end if
Loop
objStreamReader.Close()
Console.WriteLine("Total: " & total)
Console.Read()
```